# How to add a value to the object group in group module?

Tags: 7, group

I have been using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module with D7 for a while, but I always regretted that there was no 'creation date' value for each group. I added a column in my database which fills in that value automatically, but I would like it to be part of the object *group* so that I can retrieve the value more easily. Ideally I want to be able to do this:

```
$group = group_load($gid);
$thedate = $group->creation_date;
```

How should I go about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups are fieldable entities, so you could add a field with a fieldname of, say, `creation_date`.

And if you'd then use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, you could create a custom rule like so:

- Rules Event: *After saving a new group*.
- Rules Action: *Set a data value*, i.e. to set the value of your `creation_date` field.

**Note**: If the field (like such `creation_date` field) does not show up within the Rules Action to be added, you may have to first add a Rules Condition like "Entity has field".

Comment: Alternatively, you could implement hook_entity_info_alter and complimentary entity hooks to add creation_date as a property of the entity,

Comment: I have created a field as suggested, but in the Rules, it does not show the field (or any other which I had created before for the group). I may need to specifiy that I have two different group types and I have added the field to only one of them.

Comment: @Pierre_colin Try adding a Rules Condition like "Entity has field" (for such "creation_date" field). That may help to have that field show up within Rules Actions.

Comment: Great! this did the trick, but  I had to do what you suggested, Pierre, otherwise the Views would not have suggested the field in the first place.

Comment: Also, to be noted, I have a rule to set the data value, but actually you can set a default value for the date field to 'now', which would do the same thing as the rule!

Comment: @Pierre_colin : merci for the extra feedback (and accept). Since my prior comment seemed to help, I somehow integrated it in my answer now also.